# Browser DNS behaviour - multiple IP addresses for single domain

Tags: web-services, browser, dns, distributed, cname

I have the following problem and I am struggling to find if a solution exists for it, or what the best practice is here.

I have a site example.com, and multiple servers with different IP addresses around the world.  I am seeing the following behaviour in my browser (Chrome) - for simplicity lets say I only have 2 IP addresses for now.

I connect to example.com and data is served from IP address A.B.C.D (server 1).  After 40 seconds or, any subsequent request (GET/POST) to example.com then resolves to W.X.Y.Z (server 2).  My issue is that I have a cookie based web session on server 1, and server 2 knows nothing about that session.  There is no kind of back-end replication I can do to sync state between both servers.

Is there any way I can force the browser to only connect to a single server once a server has served the first page?  I am using RR DNS with multiple A records at the moment. Would switching to CNAME solve this problem?

One solution I was thinking of was having each server reply with a configured domain in the http headers (e.g. server1 would reply with X-HEADER: server1.example.com, server2 would reply with X-HEADER: server2.example.com) and then force the browser to make requests to these.  I would then have a single IP address for server1.example.com, and another for server2.example.com.  Does this break same-origin policy though? If I am on example.com can I send GET/POST/PUT etc. to server1.example.com?

I'd really appreciate any advice on this - I'm so confused!

Comment: Please can someone advise if this is a correct way to deploy with multiple IP addresses for an A-record lookup?